# Share (/mirror) entire contents of one Ubuntu server onto another

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba

I am trying to mirror everything from our group's main Ubuntu server to another Ubuntu server so as to use it for extra processing power. I have created a samba share of '/' and have mounted it under /mnt using mount.cifs. However I cannot figure out the permissions. Basically, I want all of the same permissions brought over. As it stands, I am able to write to my shared home directory, but other users are not.

Comment: It's better to use `rsync -aX`.

Comment: I ended up using an nfs share. This seems to work fine for any and all files that I need to mirror. The issue now is telling the client to use the shared programs (in /mnt) rather than those on the base OS. I am particularly looking for this functionality for a shared PostgreSQL database.